# partial deconstruction in pattern-matching (F#)

Tags: constructor, f#, pattern-matching

Following a minimal example of an observation (that kind of astonished me):

```
type Vector = V of float*float

// complete unfolding of type is OK
let projX (V (a,_)) = a

// also works
let projX' x =
   match x with
   | V (a, _) -> a

// BUT:
// partial unfolding is not Ok 
let projX'' (V x) = fst x

// consequently also doesn't work 
let projX''' x =
   match x with
   | V y -> fst y
```

What is the reason that makes it impossible to match against a partially deconstructed type?

Some partial deconstructions seem to be ok:

```
// Works
let f (x,y) = fst y
```

EDIT:
Ok, I now understand the "technical" reason of the behavior described (Thanks for your answers & comments). However, I think that language wise, this behavior feels a bit "unnatural" compared to rest of the language:

"Algebraically", to me, it seems strange to distinguish a type "t" from the type "(t)". Brackets (in this context) are used for giving precedence like e.g. in "(t * s) * r" vs "t * (s * r)". Also fsi answers accordingly, whether I send

```
type Vector = (int * int)
```

or

```
type Vector = int * int
```

to fsi, the answer is always

> type Vector = int * int

Given those observations, one concludes that "int * int" and "(int * int)" denote exactly the same types and thus that all occurrences of one could in any piece of code be replaced with the other (ref. transparency)... which as we have seen is not true.

Further it seems significant that in order to explain the behavior at hand, we had to resort to talk about "how some code looks like after compilation" rather than about semantic properties of the language which imo indicates that there are some "tensions" between language semantics an what the compiler actually does.

Comment: Try it with `type Vector = V of (float*float)` instead to make the compiler use an actual tuple for the contents.

Comment: it works! ...but how could it make a difference... I mean 
type Vector = (V of float)*float would not even be valid?

Comment: The question is: does `V of x*y` mean "V holds a tuple of items of types x and y" or "V holds two distinct fields of type x and y"?  If you don't parenthesize the tuple then the compiler assumes the latter, but if you do parenthesize it, it means the former.  This distinction mainly matters for interop with other .NET languages, but as you've found it can also affect how you interact with values of such a type within F# in some circumstances.

Comment: thx for your comment, please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In F#

```
type Vector = V of float*float
```

is just a degenerated union (you can see that by hovering it in Visual Studio), so it's equivalent to:

```
type Vector = 
    | V of float*float
```

The part after `of` creates two [anonymous field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx)s (as described in F# reference) and a constructor accepting two parameters of type float.

If you define

```
type Vector2 = 
    | V2 of (float*float)
```

there's only one anonymous field which is a tuple of floats and a constructor with a single parameter. As it was pointed out in the comment, you can use `Vector2` to do desired pattern matching.

After all of that, it may seem illogical that following code works:

```
let argsTuple = (1., 1.)
let v1 = V argsTuple
```

However, if you take into account that there's a hidden pattern matching, everything should be clear.

EDIT:

[F# language spec (p 122)](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf) states clearly that parenthesis matter in union definitions:

> Parentheses are significant in union definitions. Thus, the following two definitions differ:
>
> `type CType = C of int * int`
>
> `type CType = C of (int * int)`
>
> The lack of parentheses in the first example indicates that the union case takes two arguments. The parentheses
>   in the second example indicate that the union case takes one argument that is a first-class tuple value.

I think that such behavior is consistent with the fact that you can define more complex patterns at the definition of a union, e.g.:

```
    type Move = 
        | M of (int * int) * (int * int)
```

Being able to use union with multiple arguments also makes much sense, especially in interop situation, when using tuples is cumbersome.

The other thing that you used:

```
type Vector = int * int
```

is a [type abbreviation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233246.aspx) which simply gives a name to a certain type. Placing parenthesis around `int * int` does not make a difference because those parenthesis will be treated as grouping parenthesis.

Comment: I (understand and) agree with all you say and I will accept that answer. However, I still think that design wise the role of parentheses in union definitions is more on the pragmatic rather than on the clean/elegant side ;). There can be union definitions where some of the parentheses are for grouping while others are as discussed before... Further definitions of the form "...= X of Y" do not only depend on Y "as a type"...

Comment: I agree that it's not the most intuitive and clean design choice in terms of syntax; on the other hand it's ugly either.